# onclick on banner slider and strip ad to take into new activity

Tags: android, firebase

In my android app, the home fragment has a banner slider, strip ad, horizontal product scrolled, and grid view product scrolled.

horizontal and grid view products are connected to Firebase, products loading from Firebase, and react app. but there is no `onclick` method on the banner slider and strip ad.

I have created a new activity for on-click on the banner slider.

now I am not getting idea where I can show the same horizontal products on this new activity. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override the Banner Slider and Strip add objects and add View.OnClickListener property to them. Then from your home fragment initialize the object that you created.